# How to populate and preselect a h:selectOneMenu?

Tags: java, jsf

I have a problem in populaing dropdown value based on ID.

View:

```html
<h:selectOneMenu id="dropDown" value="#{sampleVo.dropDownType}" ">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Select Value" itemLabel="Select Value" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{sampleService.dropDownList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

`SampleVo`:

```
public class SampleVo implements Serializable {

    private String dropDownType;

    // getters and setters
}
```

`SampleService`:

```
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {

    private List<SampleVo> listOfSampleVo;
    private List<String> dropDownList;

    public void onLoad() {
        dropDownFunction();
    }

    public void dropDownFunction() {
        if (dropDownList == null) {
            dropDownList = new ArrayList<String>();
            dropDownList.add("ONE");
            dropDownList.add("TWO");
            dropDownList.add("THREE");
        }
    }   

}
```

DB Structure:

```
    SAMPLE_ID       SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION
        1                   ONE
        2                   TWO
        3                   THREE
```

During the page loading, all three drop down values would get populated with default "select value" as the first option. Drop down values are mapped to database, with sample ID. If a record exists in DB (i.e sample id = 2, sample description = TWO), I want to show two in drop down based on ID. How can I achieve this?

Comment: so ... what is your actual problem ? have you describe it and I haven't seen it yet ? do you get any error or anything ?

Comment: if a user selects THREE from drop down, I need to save 3 in Sample ID column

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dropDownList being a String list, make it a [SelectItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) list. You can set the value and label independently this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SampleVO {
    private int value;
    private String name;
    //getter & setter
}
```

In your xhtml

```
<f:selectItems value="#{sampleService.dropDownList}" var="v" itemLabel="#{v.name}" itemValue="#{v.value}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you need a custom Converter

You can take a look [here](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/53-using-converters-in-jsf-3.html)

Check the implementation for getAsString() and getAsObject() and customize it for what you need.

hint. getAsString should return TWO and getAsObject should return the whole SampleVO object.

le: @Pablo you are right .. he needs that too

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, have you want to get default selected value is (sample id =2, sample description = TWO) when your page was loaded.So you should initialize this value in your "dropDownType" variable.Your xhtml is wrong.If you used f:selectItems tag, you should remove f:selectItem tag.

Answer (score 0):

change  dropDownFunction() 
make it a List

```
public List<SelectItem> dropDownItems() {
    ArrayList<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    items.add(new SelectItem(1,"ONE");
    items.add(new SelectItem(2,"TWO");
    items.add(new SelectItem(3,"TREE");
}
```

And change dropDownType to type integer